# Не полностью прокручивающийся скроллбар

Tags: html, css, прокрутка, scrollbar

С вопросом [Неправильная ширина скроллбара на странице](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1326102/%d0%9d%d0%b5%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%8f-%d1%88%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d1%81%d0%ba%d1%80%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%bb%d0%b1%d0%b0%d1%80%d0%b0-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%86%d0%b5?noredirect=1#comment2343321_1326102) справился. Теперь возник вопрос почему скроллбар не полностью прокручивается. Есть код

```css
.CatalogMenuLeft {
    width: 25%;
}

.CatalogMenuRight {
    /*height: 1278px;*/
}

.catalogheader {
    width: 100%;
    height: 30%;
    /*display: flex;*/
    /*justify-content: center;*/
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto; 
}


.crossline, .bottompart {
    flex: 1;
    /*width: 100%;*/
    /*height: 33%;*/
}

.crosslineright {
    width: 100%;
    /*margin-top: 40px;*/
    /*margin-left: 20px;*/
    /*margin-right: 20px;*/
    /*align: right;*/
    text-align: right;
}

.windowheader {
    flex: 1;
    /*width: 100%;*/
    /*height: calc(100% - 2*37.5px);*/
    /*height: 34%;*/
    margin: auto;
    text-align: center;
}

.windowheader h4 {
    flex: 1;
    /*width: 100%;*/
    margin: auto;
    text-align: center;
}

.flexdisabledscrollbar1, .flexdisabledscrollbar2, .flexdisabledscrollbar3 {
    flex: 0;
    width: 5px;
    border-right: 5px solid #f5f5f6;    
}

.flexline1 {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    height: 33%;
}

.flexline2 {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    height: 34%;
}

.flexline3 {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    height: 33%;
}

.flexcontent {
    display: flex;
    /*overflow-y: scroll;*/
    /*height: 70%;*/
}

.menulistitem_selected {
    font-weight: bold;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.menulistitem_selected::after {
    content: "\2192";
    /*position: absolute;*/
    margin-left: 5px;
    display: inline-block;
    font-weight: 400;
    transition: all .1s ease;
}

.close {
        margin-top: -14px;
        padding-top: 5px;
        padding-left: 5px;
        padding-right: 5px;
        font-size: 24px;
        cursor: pointer;
        display: inline-block;
}


.CatalogMenuRight {
    /*flex: 1;*/
    overflow: auto;
    height: 600px;
}


/*.menulistitem {
    padding-top: 5px;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
}
*/

/* Works on Firefox */

.CatalogMenuRight {
  scrollbar-width: auto;
  scrollbar-color: #b8b8bc #f5f5f6;
  /*overflow-y: scroll;*/
  /*height: 200px;*/
}


/* Works on Chrome, Edge, and Safari */

.CatalogMenuRight::-webkit-scrollbar-button {
    display: none;
}

.CatalogMenuRight::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 5px;
}

.CatalogMenuRight::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  background: #f5f5f6;
}

.CatalogMenuRight::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background: #b8b8bc;
  border-radius: 2.5px;
  border: 0px solid #f5f5f6;
}

.CatalogMenuRight::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover {
    background: #b8b8bc;
}

#dropdownwindowright {
    width: 75%;
}

.CatalogMenuSearch #SearchBlock {
    /*border-bottom: 1px solid orange;*/
}

#SearchBlock {
    padding-top: 5px;
    /*padding-left: 25px;*/
    margin-left: 25px;
    margin-right: 50px;
    /*padding-right: 50px;*/
    display: flex;
    /*justify-content: flex-end;*/
    height: 35px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #dfdfe1;
}

#SearchInputdiv {
    height: 100%;
    width: calc(100%-35px);
    flex: 1;
    /*color: #dfdfe1;*/
    /*flex: calc(100%-35px);*/
}

#SearchInput {
    width: 100%;
    border-top: none;
    border-left: none;
    border-right: none;
    border-bottom: none;
}

#SearchButtondiv {
    height: 100%;
    justify-content: flex-end;
    width: 35px;
    /*flex: 35px;*/
}

#SearchButton button svg{
    vertical-align: middle;
    fill: #dfdfe1;
    /*justify-content: flex-end;
    flex: 35px;*/
}

#SearchButton {
  outline: none;
  border: none;
  background: transparent;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#SearchButton:active {
  outline: 1px solid blue;
}

#menulist {
  flex: 1;
  overflow: auto;
  height: 462px;
}

.menulistitem {
  padding-top: 5px;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
}


/* Works on Firefox */

#menulist {
  scrollbar-width: auto;
  scrollbar-color: #b8b8bc #f5f5f6;
  /*overflow-y: scroll;*/
  /*height: 200px;*/
}


/* Works on Chrome, Edge, and Safari */

#menulist::-webkit-scrollbar-button {
  display: none;
}

#menulist::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 5px;
}

#menulist::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  background: #f5f5f6;
}

#menulist::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background: #b8b8bc;
  border-radius: 2.5px;
  border: 0px solid #f5f5f6;
}

#menulist::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover {
  background: #b8b8bc;
}
```

```html
<div class="CatalogMenuLeft">
  <div class="catalogheader">
    <div class="flexline1">
      <div class="crossline">
      </div>
      <div class="flexdisabledscrollbar1">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="flexline2">
      <div class="windowheader">
        <h4>Каталог</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="flexdisabledscrollbar2">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="flexline3">
      <div class="bottompart">
      </div>
      <div class="flexdisabledscrollbar3">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="flexcontent">
    <div class="windowmenulist" id="menulist">
      <div class="menulistitem" id="smartphonesandgadgets">
        Смартфоны и гаджеты
      </div>
      <div class="menulistitem" id="notebooksandpcs">
        Ноутбуки и компьютеры
      </div>
      <div class="menulistitem" id="tvsaudiovideohifi">
        Телевизоры, аудио-видео, Hi-Fi
      </div>
      <div class="menulistitem" id="householdappliancesforhomeandkitchen">
        Бытовая техника для дома и кухни
      </div>
      <div class="menulistitem" id="constructionandrepair">
        Строительство и ремонт
      </div>
      <div class="menulistitem" id="houseandcottage">
        Дом и дача
      </div>
      <div class="menulistitem" id="photosvideossecuritysystems">
        Фото, видео, системы безопасности
      </div>
      <div class="menulistitem" id="automotiveproducts">
        Автотовары
      </div>
      <div class="menulistitem" id="officesuppliesfurnitureandofficeequipment">
        Канцтовары, Мебель и Офисная техника
      </div>
      <div class="menulistitem" id="beautyandhealth">
        Красота и здоровье
      </div>
      <div class="menulistitem" id="sportsandrecreation">
        Спорт и отдых
      </div>
      <div class="menulistitem" id="productsforgamers">
        Товары для геймеров
      </div>
      <div class="menulistitem" id="discountedproducts">
        Уцененные товары
      </div>
      <div class="menulistitem" id="giftcertificates">
        Подарочные сертификаты
      </div>
      <div class="menulistitem" id="services">
        Сервисы и услуги
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Но у меня прокручивается не полностью (привожу скриншот ниже)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пункт меню Сервисы и услуги не отображается при прокрутке вниз.

Answer (score 0):

Необходимо было использовать

```css
#menulist {
  flex: 1;
  overflow: auto;
  height: 420px;
}
```